# How to implement partial vehicle are networking and partial non-networking in Veins?

Tags: veins, traffic-simulation

I want to simulate a traffic scenario with a mix of connected vehicles and human driven vehicles. How can I set up these two types of vehicles separately in Veins? Should I generate the vehicles in the sumo rou.xml file or in the Veins ini file?

Also, I would appreciate it if any book or learning video recommendations related to this.